# Vue JS toggle class on individual items rendered with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drag-and-drop, v-for

I am using the v-for directive to render a list .

```
<li v-for="group in groupList" :key="group.id" @dragenter="toggleClass ...."@dragleave="toggleClass ...." >

  Content

   </li>
```

What I want is to add a class to the `li` on which the `dragenter` event is fired ?
How can I accomplish this ?
How do I even get a reference to the item (the item,not the data property of the parent component)in the first place inside the event handle?and even If I get the reference how to toggle the class from there?
Thanks.
I know vue is data-driven , change the data to reflect on the DOM but I would like a concise solution to this rather than index/Id on the data-model based solutions.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can access the `li` being dragged in the `dragenter`-callback by accessing `event.currentTarget` (or even `event.target` would work in this case), where `event` is the callback's parameter.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      grouplist: [
        { id: 1, text: 'a' },
        { id: 2, text: 'b' },
        { id: 3, text: 'c' },
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onDragEnter(e) {
      e.currentTarget.classList.add('drag-enter');
    },
    onDragLeave(e) {
      e.currentTarget.classList.remove('drag-enter');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.drag-enter {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p draggable>Drag this text over the list items below</p>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="group in grouplist"
        :key="group.id"
        @dragenter="onDragEnter"
        @dragleave="onDragLeave">{{group.text}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but while using frameworks such as vue it's best to let the framework handle the DOM maniputations. Never mind , I figured a way out . Will post here shortly